# Request.host in initializer Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apartment-gem

I am using the Apartment gem for a multi-tenant app and I'm using the "host_hash elevator" to switch the tenant based on the subdomain and host of the request.

This is done with the below code (from their documentation):

```
#initalizers/apartment.rb

# application.rb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::HostHash', {'example.com' => 'example_tenant'}
  end
end
```

Where it says 'example.com' => 'example_tenant' I need to send a hash with the request.host to find the company in my Company model where the value of the request_host database field matches request.host. If that makes sense?

if I hard code in an example so it's like the below code I can get it to work, but I don't know how to dynamically do it based on the request:

```
#initalizers/apartment.rb

# application.rb
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::HostHash', {'test.lvh.me:3000' => 'test.lvh.me:3000'}
  end
end
```

The above code works because that's the domain that I'm currently on and it matches a field and apartment tenant that I had set up.

However, since this in an initializer when I put 'request.host' there I get an error: undefined local variable/method 'request'

If I use 'Rack::Request.new(env).host' I get undefined local variable/method 'env'

How can I get request.host in an an initializer to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to some help I got on the apartment gem's github issues I was able to figure out a solution.

```
#company.rb model
def self.full_hosts_hash
    Company.all.inject(Hash.new) do |hash, company|
      hash[company.request_host] = company.request_host
      hash
    end
end

#apartment.rb initializer
require 'apartment/elevators/host_hash'
Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::HostHash', Company.full_hosts_hash
```